# Why am I getting "Cannot add foreign key constraint" error with the following sql command?

Tags: mysql

I am getting an error while running the following commands on a MySQL server.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    userID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(userID),
    firstname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    hashpass VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB ;


CREATE TABLE posts (
    postID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    text VARCHAR(1000),
    imageURI VARCHAR(100),
    userID VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY(postID),

    FOREIGN KEY (userID)
    REFERENCES users (userID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,

    tags VARCHAR(500)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: Incompatible types. `users.userID` is an `INT` whereas `posts.userID` is a `VARCHAR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the same type of your primary keys - `users.userID int` - on the foreign keys - `posts.userID` - as well.

**[WORKING SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/adf08)**

Try like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
userID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(userID),
firstname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
hashpass VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB ;


CREATE TABLE posts (

postID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
text VARCHAR(1000),
imageURI VARCHAR(100),
userID INT NOT NULL,     <---Change here

PRIMARY KEY(postID),

FOREIGN KEY (userID)
REFERENCES users (userID)
ON DELETE CASCADE,

tags VARCHAR(500)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 0):

your foreign key

```
userID VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
```

is different with

```
userID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```